# How to get home wallpaper offset?

Tags: android

I get wallpaper by `BitmapDrawable drawable = (BitmapDrawable) getWallpaper();`
But I need know now home wallpaper offset.
How can I do?
thanks

Comment: sorry, I frist use this to do ask question.so I don`t know there have comment. offset mean I need know home page wallpaper offset.Because I need my activity can draw wallpaper same as haome page.Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

If you add this to your Manifest for your activity you'll no longer get the scrunched wallpaper which I'm guessing you want to avoid.

```
<activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Wallpaper">
```

You don't need anything in your java code.  Make you you don't set you layout background in your xml or set it to @null.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! :) Please note the difference between SO and other web "forums" you might be familiar with. SO is for _questions_ and _answers_. While "work on your grammar" might be an alright _comment_, don't forget that you can simply edit questions or answers to improve their grammar. Not everyone here is a native English speaker, and we can help them learn and make reading easier on everyone by editing posts for clarity. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

No way as far as I can tell. But you can always explicitly set offsets, so it does not really matter to not able to get offsets.